# Pythonanywhere, point default app to my app instead of welcome--web2py

Tags: web2py, pythonanywhere

This is a simple question I imagine, how can I point default app to my app instead of welcome app in pythonanywhere? Web2py app is used.

Answer (score 4):

There are several options, as discussed [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Application-init). For the URL rewrite option, include the following in your routes.py file:

```
routers = dict(
    BASE = dict(
        default_application = 'myapp'
    )
)
```